# Model is null after post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**EDIT: It appears I approached this problem the wrong way.  I will explain what I need to happen**

Here is my model:

```
public class  Items 
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public bool Picked { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller:

```
public class InvoiceController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            using (TPGEntities context = new TPGEntities())
            {
                List<Items> result = (from a in context.IV00101
                                      select new Items { ItemName = a.ITEMDESC, Type = a.ITEMNMBR, Picked = false }).Take(10).ToList();

                return View(result);
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string searchTerm, IList<Items> model)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

And my view:

```
@model IList<SampleEnterprise.Models.Items>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Repair Invoicing";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Repair Invoicing</h2>

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "partsList" }))
    {
        <input type="search" name="searchTerm" />
        <input type="submit" value="OK" />

        <div id="partsList">

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <h1>@item.ItemName</h1>
                <div>@item.Type</div>
                <div>
                    @if (@item.Picked)
                    {
                        <img src="~/Images/checkbox.png" />
                    }
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    }
```

Basically here is what I need to happen:

1. User goes to page.  In a textbox I don't have currently on my view, the user will type in a number.  That number will be used to lookup and return data from the entity framework.  This list of data needs to be stored temporarily somehow.
2. I will use the for each loop in razor to display the temp data.
3. In the search textbox, the user will search the temp data for an itemnumber.
4. If item number exits in temp data, set picked to true.
5. Repeat until all the picked properties are set to true.

Comment: You can post only `Form Fields` like `input`, `select` etc. Hence you do `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ItemName)` or `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ItemName)`

Answer (score 2):

You're not creating any input elements for the `Items`, so nothing gets posted back.

Comment: I don't really want input fields, since the user won't be doing any editing.  The only time the model will get modified, is from my controller.

Comment: So why do you want your items posted back? HTTP is stateless. You cannot get the items you display on the view posted back, unless you add for example hidden input elements for each of them. Just load the items from the database in the HttpPost method.

Comment: Because I want the search textbox to search through my model.  I only need to pull data from the database once.

Comment: That is not possible. Upon submit, the entities you retrieved from the database are gone, unless you also post those, or cache them somewhere.

Comment: So really what I need is a session or something similar?

Comment: I don't know, I don't think so, it depends on what you want to do. Please update your question to explain very detailed what you are trying to do, because now with every comment a new question arises. :-)

Comment: When you explain it like that, it does look like you could benefit from using the Session. :-)

Comment: Ok.  How would I loop through my session in the razor view though?

Comment: You don't, you assign the cached items to the model before passing it to the view.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I just started MVC a few days ago.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted those fields to be returned you would need to create hidden fields for them.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ItemName)
```

Then they would get returned as expected.

To be honest though I would probably just populate the model in the action method, as really all you want returned in the post is the search term.

Answer (score 2):

`<h1>@item.ItemName</h1>` and `<div>@item.Type</div>` are simply turning into plain text (e.g., `<h1>Item</h1>`) and have no binding to the model once converted to HTML.  You would need to store them in something the controller action can understand, using `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ItemName)` or creating your own HTML Helper like @Html.DivFor, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the error and all you need to add is a the hidden field in order for it to fetch the value. You can do something like `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ItemName)` since your doing it inside the form.